# Not able to fetch values from Cassandra using DataStax C# Driver

Tags: c#, asp.net, cassandra, cql

I have a Cassandra Database and recently I had added a second node with it.I have a old application developed in **`C#.net`** and backend as **`Cassandra`** which was developed during only one node was present its is connecting to the DB and fetching the values via **`Datastax C# Driver`** even though when there are two node present now.

But When I Create a new application in **`C#.net`** to the Cassandra now with two nodes via **`Datastax C# Driver`** its is connecting and I am getting **`session`** but when I try to fetch the values from the DB I am getting this error

> Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LocalQuorum (2
>   required but only 1 alive)

Do I have to change anything in the **Cassandra Config(cassandra.yaml)** file in order to connect new applications.

I am struck with the problem for days.Kindly anyoneone point me what to do to solve this issue.

**Edit:** 
I am getting this issue only on new version **`Datastax Cassandra C# Driver V.3.0.0.1 - Beta - 1`** when I removed this reference and added **`Datastax Cassandra C# Driver V.2.7.1`** I didn't get the error.But this may not be root cause of this issue I am still searching for the root cause and solution for it.

Comment: Are you using vnodes? Which Cassandra version? What is the output of `nodetool status`?

Comment: Have you check the [docs on adding a new node to an existing cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html)?

Comment: @jorgebg I had `nodetool status` both my nodes are Up and Running `Cassandra 2.1.8.689`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added your node did you also increase your replication factor (RF)?

The biggest problem I see is that you are running a two node cluster and querying at quorum.

[image: Don't do this]

In this scenario, you can only tolerate a single node being unavailable (as you are seeing).

[image]

Quorum of 2 == 2.  So if you only have 2 nodes, then quorum only works if both nodes are running and if your keyspace has an RF of 2. There is no tolerance for node failure in this scenario.

Seriously, don't do this.  Query at `LOCAL_ONE` instead.

Comment: I have set the Replication factor to 2 and I checked the node status both are Up and running.